# HessianMatrix (norm[2](x)) in Wolfram

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I'm very new to Wolfram-alpha. I'm trying to compute the Hessian Matrix of ||x|| where x is a vector. I tried this command HessianMatrix (norm[2][x])   in mathematica 13 where I use Wolframalpha input cell but nothing happens. Any idea ? I'm probably lacking some basic knowledge.

Comment: Input HessianMatrix (norm[2](x)) , expected outpit :  some expression with A and x

Comment: I don't need a  numeric solution I want a symbolic solution

Comment: HessianMatrix (norm[2](x))  is symbolic input,  right ?  x is a symbol for a vector. The expected output  is some expression with the symbol x which I don't know but want it to be computed.

Answer (score 1):

In WolframAlpha, you can get the Hessian determinant for a multivariable function $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ with the syntax

```
Hessian matrix (or determinant) f(x1, x2, ...)
```

This usually also works if you have additional parameters, in which case one should specify which variables to use in the component derivatives, e.g.

```
Hessian matrix f(x1, x2, y) w.r.t. {x1, x2}
```

Both matrix and determinant are included in either flavor of input. For your use case, one would resort to

```
Hessian matrix norm({x, y, z})
```

[image]

As you can see, the output doesn't know how to handle derivatives of the built-in `Abs` function (absolute value). Sadly, there doesn't appear to be any means elaborating on the WA query and introducing extra conditions on the variables, such as fixing $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3$. However, we can reduce `Abs'[x]` and `Abs''[x]` based on the sign of `x` so cleaning up the output isn't a difficult task.

Since you mentioned you were working in a notebook, you *can* carry out this cleanup with the following code:

```
D[Norm[{x, y, z}], {{x, y, z}, 2}]
(* Hessian matrix *)

Simplify[% /. Abs -> RealAbs, Element[{x, y, z}, Reals]]
(* in the Hessian, replace Abs with RealAbs, then simplify assuming all arguments are real *)
```

Why `RealAbs`? Because `Abs` is blind to the domain of `x`, whereas `RealAbs` assumes a purely real argument. According to [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealAbs.html), it's implemented as a `Piecewise` function; see what happens when you run

```
PiecewiseExpand[RealAbs[x]]
PiecewiseExpand[RealAbs'[x]]
PiecewiseExpand[RealAbs''[x]]
```

vs the same inputs with `Abs`.

I also assume `norm[2]` refers to the $2$-norm, which is implemented as `Norm[f]`, but if you happened to mean something else, you may specify a different $p$-norm using the syntax `Norm[f, p]`.